# Forgot to include information in mercurial commit description

Tags: version-control, mercurial

If you make a commit in mercurial:

```
hg commit -m "an incomplete description of the commit"
```

what are your options for correcting the commit description? <strike>Should I just immediately commit again with the complete description?</strike>

### edit

Actually, you can't commit without something having changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
hg rollback
```

It undoes the last commit completely.  You can then recommit with a proper message.

Comment: As long as you haven't pushed the change (or had it pulled)